# Jquery: get next button of a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet of code:

```
$(':checkbox[name="privacy"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $("label[for='privacy']").css('color','inherit');
            $('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('button[type=submit]').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary');
        }
        else
        {
            $("label[for='privacy']").css('color','#B94A48');
            $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('button[type=submit]').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger');
        }
    });
```

And this is the form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" class="ajax-validation" action="{{ @ABSOLUTE_PATH }}{{ @ALIASES.url_newsletter }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="required-label">Email *</label>
            <input class="form-control required-field" name="email" type="text" placeholder="La tua email" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="privacy">
                <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" value="1" checked />
                <a href="{{ @ABSOLUTE_PATH }}{{ @ALIASES.url_privacy }}">Accettazione privacy</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-at"></i> Iscriviti
        </button>
    </form>
```

Basically I need to disable only the button relative at same form that contain that checkbox (and no others eventually inserted in same page).

I tried with

```
[...]
$(this).next('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
[...]
```

How I can get only the submit present in same form of the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j33j9rog/)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);`

And if you have multiple forms, you want to go up the DOM from the button to avoid interfering with other forms:

`$(this).closest('form').find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents("form").find("button[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled')
```

the above could work for finding only the button in the form you are on, however it is messy.

ids would be useful when creating multiple forms

Comment: You can avoid these multiple `.parent()`-calls when you use `.parents('form')` instead. And please add quotation marks in your `find`-function.